# Is it possible to initialise a Google Cloud Storage Client in C++ with an OAuth2 token?

Tags: c++, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am unable to provide a credentials file to authenticate to Google Cloud Storage. I was wondering whether it was possible to use the newly added oauth2 library in google-cloud-cpp Client Library to create an OAauth2 token and initialise a storage client?

I have tried the following to create an OAuth token:

```
auto const expiration = std::chrono::system_clock::now() + std::chrono::minutes(15);
auto credentials = google::cloud::MakeAccessTokenCredentials(access_key, expiration);
auto generator = google::cloud::oauth2::MakeAccessTokenGenerator(*credentials);
auto token = generator->GetToken();
```

I was wondering if it was possible to initialise a `google::cloud::storage::Client()` with this access token?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to provide the `credentials` object when initializing the `Client`.  Assuming the `access_key` variable in your sample code is a thing convertible to `std::string` and contains an access *token*, then you can use this:

```cc
namespace g = google::cloud;

auto const expiration = std::chrono::system_clock::now() + std::chrono::minutes(15);
auto credentials = g::MakeAccessTokenCredentials(access_key, expiration);

auto client = g::storage::Client(
    g::Options{}.set<g::UnifiedCredentialsOption>(credential));
```

If you have something other than an access token, then you need to use one of the other factory functions to create a `std::shared_ptr<g::Credentials>`:

https://cloud.google.com/cpp/docs/reference/common/latest/group__guac.html#functions